# LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES crashes my app

Tags: java, android, c++, android-ndk

I am trying to use a C library (apriltag) in my android app (4.4) using the NDK.
I prebuilt the library using the android toolchain.
After that, I followed this tutorial ([link](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/prebuilts.html)) to use apriltag in my C++ module.

My android.mk :

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := apriltag_prebuilt_lib
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/prebuilt/libapriltag.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := gle_main
...
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -landroid -llog -lEGL -lGLESv2
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES += apriltag_prebuilt_lib
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := cpufeatures android_native_app_glue ndk_helper
```

However, as soon as I reference it in another module, my app cannot even start. Android monitor tells me that process has died. If I comment the line LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES I can start it but cannot use apriltag in my module...

Also, it works on Android 7. With this device I get the invalid DT_NEEDED entry "app/build/.../libapriltag.so" error for libgle_main.so (the c++ module that uses apriltag).

Any ideas to get it work on my Android 4.4 device ?

**EDIT 1:**
I've added to my Activity :

```
static {
    System.loadLibrary("apriltag");
    System.loadLibrary("gle_main");
}
```

But now, I get this error :

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "sqrt" referenced by "/data/app/com.laas.lumus_app-1/lib/arm/libapriltag.so"
```

I guess it is related to the math library so I added to my `gle_main` and my `apriltag_prebuilt_lib`.

```
LOCAL_LDLIBS += -lm
```

Nothing changed.

Now, the app doesnt start on the 4.4 AND the 7.0 device.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I decided to put all the source files in my project to build it entierely with Android Studio and not with the external toolchain.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using a prebuilt shared library, `libapriltag.so`. You have to let gradle add it to your apk also, and then you can use it into `gle_main`. You have to add this line to your module/build.gradle script

```
android{
    sourceSets.main{
         jniLibs.srcDir 'path_to_libapriltag'
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your time. I added <code>jniLibs.srcDirs = ['src/main/jniLibs']</code> but nothing changed.